# Run code once for new visitors with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, session

I am using laravel 8 and I am creating a world wide webshop.

There are 2 currencies available: usd & euro.

But how can i run code only once when a new visitor comes to my website?

What i want to do is check if someone lives in europe and set the currency to euro, otherwise set it to usd.

But this code should only run once per visitor because they can change the currency and it should not automatically transfer back to the original currency.

Comment: one way is to store the currency in the cookie, first check whether the cookie exists, if not, store currency based on geolocation (there is a laravel package for that), otherwise use the cookie value

Comment: Are these guest users or authenticated users?

Comment: Coockie is the way to go, and Laravel can handle this via Coockies very well.

Comment: @Rwd yes there are guest users, but I have managed to use Anurat Chapanond solution by checking if there is an empty cookie and set it automatically for the first time. The user can then manually edit the cookie whenever he wants.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get their IP address from the Request object, either by DI-ing in the controller method, or the helper, `request()->ip()`. Run the IP through a geolocation API, and log it in your database.

Might want to trigger this off creating an account though, or else have some garbage collection of older records, or else that visitor_location log could get a little cumbersome.

Comment: Getting their ip address and their location is not the problem, I can figure that out. But the problem is how to only run this code once per visitor regardless if they have an account or not.

Comment: By logging it. Or by sending back a cookie without an expiration that the script checks for first. There's no way to grantee they won't clear then of course, but that's probably infrequent enough to not worry about it.